# OpenGL rendering performance - default shader or no shader?

Tags: performance, opengl, shader

I have some code for rendering a video, so the OpenGL side of it (once the rendered frame is available in the target texture) is very simple: Just render it to the target rectangle.

What complicates things a bit is that I am using a third-party SDK to render the UI, so I cannot know what state changes it makes, and therefore every time I am rendering a frame I have to make sure all the states I need are set correctly.

I am using a vertex and a texture coordinate buffer to draw my rectangle like this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);            
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, texHandle);            
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

glPushClientAttrib( GL_CLIENT_VERTEX_ARRAY_BIT );
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glEnableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );            
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer);
glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_texCoordBuffer);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
glPopClientAttrib();
```

(Is there anything that I can skip - even when not knowing what is happening inside the UI library?)

Now I wonder -and this is more theoretical as I suppose there won't be much difference when just drawing one Quad- if it is theoretically faster to just render like the above, or instead write a simple default vertex and fragment shader that does maybe nothing more than returning ftransform() for the position and uses the default way for the fragment color too?

I wonder if by using a shader I can skip certain state changes, or generally speed up things. Or if by using the above code OpenGL internally just does that and the outcome will be exactly the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are worried about clobbering the UI SDK state, you should wrap the code with glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT | GL_TEXTURE_BIT) ... glPopAttrib() as well.

You could simplify the state management code a bit by using a vertex array object.

As to using a shader, for this simple program I wouldn't bother. It would be one more bit of state you'd have to save & restore, and you're right that internally OpenGL is probably doing just that for the same outcome.

On speeding things up: performance is going to be dominated by the cost of sending tens? hundreds? of kilobytes of video frame data to the GPU, and adding or removing OpenGL calls is very unlikely to make a difference. I'd look first at possible differences in frame rate between the UI and video stream: for example, if the frame rate is faster, arrange for the video data to be copied once and re-used instead of copying it each time the UI is redrawn.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the info, I know that in my case I won't need to worry about the performance for this drawing object, I just want to learn more and improve more overall techniques. Thanks for the hints you gave me, I will apply them.

Comment: P.S. if you are interested in the setup of my rendering, I posted another question about multithreading issues I have currently in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680883/opengl-multithreaded-video-rendering-shows-severe-flickering-issues-mac-specifi - I am already trying to redraw the same frame more than once if the framerate is higher than the usual 24 fps I have in the videos